# Is possible to get JavaFX thread pendingRunnables size

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

All GUI logic have to be done on GUI thread (by `Platform.ranLater`).
Is there way to get the queue size of this thread (pendingRunnables size in PlatformImpl)?

Comment: No: at least, not without a lot of reflection-based hacking. What do you need this for?

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I want to monitoring somehow GUI freezing/Slow (without hacks). It's happened only once (freeze), but I can't reproduce it even using stress tests (of days)